# Mobilenet vs SSD

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, object-detection

I have some confusion between mobilenet and SSD. As far as I know, mobilenet is a neural network that is used for classification and recognition whereas the SSD is a framework that is used to realize the multibox detector. Only the combination of both can do object detection. Thus, mobilenet can be interchanged with resnet, inception and so on. SSD can be interchanged with RCNN. Are my statements correct?

Comment: Yes. But there is a version of Mobilenet called MobilenetSSD that can do MultiObject Detection:
https://github.com/chuanqi305/MobileNet-SSD

Answer (score 19):

There are two types of deep neural networks here. Base network and detection network. MobileNet, VGG-Net, LeNet, and all of them are based on networks. The Base network provides high-level features for classification or detection. If you use a fully connected layer at the end of these networks, you have a classification. But you can remove the fully connected layer and replace it with detection networks, like SSD, Faster R-CNN, and so on.
In fact, SSD use of last convolutional layer on base networks for the detection task.
MobileNet just like other base networks uses convolution to produce high-level features.

Comment: Would you say that this also it the case with SSD Inception models? From this: https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Inception-Single-Shot-MultiBox-Detector-for-object-Ning-Zhou/26c35c20fb7f5b354fb72bad867b8b54b07e2bd3/figure/2

It seems that the VGG16 base network is still present but the Inception is added in the SSD part of the architecture. I am using the SSD Inception v2 from TensorFlow models, and I am confused if this assumption I make is correct: The SSD Inception v2 model replaces the VGG16 neural network used for feature extraction with the Inception v2 network. Am I correct here?